# How can I make an input change its src with an onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm trying this and my background changes color (what I want) but the src of the input only changes on the second time I click it. how can I make it change the source on the first click? Also how can I change the src back to the original with a second click?

```
<input id="showHideContainer" type="image" src="on.png " height="3%" width="2%" alt="On" onclick="toggle();">

<script>
document.getElementById('showHideContainer').onclick = function () {
divTest = document.getElementById('header');
if (divTest.style.display === "none") {
    divTest.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    divTest.style.display = "none";
};
$('body').toggleClass('style2');
$('#showHideContainer').click(function(){
$('#showHideContainer').attr('src', 'off.png');
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why not have all the code for the click event be in a single handler? There are two separate click events for the same element.

Comment: could you show me how that should look? sorry I'm a noob

Comment: @AustinJones OP is attaching another eventhandler on the first click, so the element gets the second eventhandler only after the first click. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix. You are now attaching anoter eventhandler on the first click on the `#showHideContainer`, that is why it's not firing the first time. This trimmed version of your code should get you the expected result, also see the other answer to look at the state of your element attribute:

```
 document.getElementById('showHideContainer').onclick = function () {
        divTest = document.getElementById('header');
        if (divTest.style.display === "none") {
            divTest.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            divTest.style.display = "none";
        };
        $('body').toggleClass('style2');
        var off = $(this).attr('src').indexOf('off.png')>-1;
        $(this).attr('src', (off?'on.png':'off.png'));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, how could I make it so the second time I click it the src goes back to the original?

Comment: @AustinJones A combined version of my answer and the answer of joyBlanks. Updated the code.

Comment: awesome! Thanks, you were a lot of help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to determine the current state of the obj then toggle it with the other

```
$('#showHideContainer').click(function(){
    var off = $(this).attr('src').indexOf('off.png')>-1;
    $(this).attr('src', (off?'on.png':'off.png'));
});
```

Comment: so this does work but the image only changes on the second click

Comment: Thanks to you too. I appreciate the help.